# How to determine image format from numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, image, qt, numpy, opencv

In my Qt application I have image data as a `numpy.ndarray`. Usually that comes from `cv2.imread()`, which I then convert to a `QImage` as follows:

```py
height, width, channel = cvImg.shape
bytesPerLine = 3 * width
qImg = QImage(cvImg.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
```

This works fine, the `QImage` can be converted to a pixmap and painted to a label. Now in some cases I don't get the image data from a file via `imread()`, but instead directly from a camera. This data is also a `numpy.ndarray`, I can save it via `cv2.imwrite()` (and then open it in an image viewer). However, using the code above I cannot convert that image data directly to a `QImage`, the result is a red-ish image without any details, just some vertical lines.

Now since I can save that camera image data it seems to be valid, I just need to find the correct image format when calling the `QImage` constructor (I guess). I tried several of them, but none worked. So how can I determine in which format this image data is?

Comment: You should be able to tell the image format from your camera settings. If that isn't possible for some reason, try looking at the `shape` and the value range of the array. That might give you a hint to whether the information is stored for example in rgb, counts, or something else or if there is an alpha channel.

Comment: @mapf It's a network camera from *The Imaging Source*, which shoud give me a 32 bit image. I can tell it has 4 channels by `cvImg.shape`. But how can i determine the **exact** format - e.g. how does openCV does it when saving the data to a file?

Comment: @Matthias The shape does not determine the format, several formats can generate the same shape. A trivial example would be an RGB and BGR image (also HSV, etc.) try with this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51608230/6622587

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you very much for the link, using the `qimage2ndarray` package that is mentioned there it works fine now. I learned however that my knowledge of all these image formats and conversions fromt/to `numpy` is less than sufficient. Do you know a good tutorial on the theory of that topic?

Comment: No, numpy has nothing to do with the format but the library that gets the information such as opencv, PIL, etc. Numpy is a library that provides a container, and the other libraries fill that container with raw data in a certain format

Comment: @eyllanesc To be fair, I didn't say the `shape` *determines* the format, I only said it might give a *hint*. Sorry if this was missleading though. Your suggestion is much better of course.